# Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity c# CreateAsync method Problems with multi language

Tags: c#

I am using Entity Framework, `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`, and this method:

```
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, string password);
```

But when I pass User Data in another language, it does not allow me to insert data in the database.

For example, I pass this Username: सागर

Comment: What exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is database encoding problem. Does database encode support सागर ?

Select utf-8 encode or select supported language encoding.

Its better to check username only contain ascii form `a to z` or `1 to 9` and convert `A to Z` to `a to z` (lower case mode to make standard username string) not other charecter and using `nikname or name` to store `सागर` with local language.

Because especial character like `सागर` does not have same value in all encoding.

Comment: Database Support Such word because I have make field nvarchar so It allow me to save Unicode

Comment: @SagarPadhiyar nvarchar is field type not database type

Comment: @SagarPadhiyar by the way its better to use standard character in username for example in arabic `ی`  is not same as `ي` but both of them is same in this word `بیب`. `بیب` can be  ` ب ی ب` or `ب ي ب`and you do not know what is user input therefore better only accept `a to z` :)